# Adding code to web.config to hide my page extensions

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, web-config

I have this web.config file and i want to add a code to it that will hide the .asp of a page in my website called "users.asp" . please how do i do it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you need the URL rewrite module installed, and you need IIS7 or above, this won't work on IIS6

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>

             <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^users/$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="users.asp" />
            </rule>

        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Recommended reading:
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: so if i want to remove another .asp from a page do i have to write this whole script again or for example make it like this: <action type="Rewrite" url="users.asp, level.asp" /> and please can you put it all together with my code for me cos i don't where to place this code

Comment: The code I've given you goes inside the `<system.webServer>` tags, and you'll need to copy paste and modify the `<rule>` element for each relevant page.  The URL rewrite module includes a "wizard" which you'll find in IIS manager which will add the rules to web.config behind the scenes if you prefer.  I really recommend you look at that link I gave you.  The point of Stack Overflow is to help users find answers themselves, rather than to write code for them.